# How do I send ESC/POS commands to thermal printer? Is there any terminal or software to send ESC/POS commnds?

Tags: escpos

I'm working with CSN A1X thermal printer.I want to print graphs like sine wave, triangular wave on thermal printer.How to send ESC/POS commands to thermal printer?I'm sending ESC/POS commands via serial terminal, but it just print text on paper rather than function of the command. NEED HELP

Comment: Hi, has my answer helped you? Can it be improved?
You could consider marking it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos). This is a python-library that implements a low-level interface for ESC/POS. It wraps the ESC/POS-commands into python-functions and should be extendable if you need any special commands.

For your task you would probably want to create images and send them to your printer if it has no special function to print graphs. (And at least the ESC/POS-definition by Epson does not know any graph-printing-functions.)

python-escpos also supports serial printers and should work on both Windows and Linux.